# vb.net reading minutes from a file

Tags: vb.net

so I have to read in the time of the song from a file and store it as minutes and seconds. So for example I have a file like this:

```
What you know?-T.I.
Rap
4.30
```

When I read it in I use this:

```
_strSong(intCount) = objReader.ReadLine()
_strGenres(intCount) = objReader.ReadLine()
```

Now I don't know how to get number 4 as minutes and 30 as seconds. Any help please?

Comment: How the file looks like? does the time will be in every third line?

Comment: Yes. So there are multiple songs and it goes line by line (name, genres, length) just like I showed one example above. Sorry for confusion.
I'm also thinking if it's a good idea to read it as a decimal number and then after try to convert it to minutes and seconds when I try to sum all the songs.

Comment: Well I'm just going to read it as a DECIMAL and then in the end I will convert the number into hh:mm:ss.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the line into a temporary string variable, then use [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) along with [`Integer.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19(v=vs.110).aspx) to separate the line into minutes and seconds:

```
Dim line As String = objReader.ReadLine()
Dim parts As String() = line.Split("."c)
Dim minutes As Integer = Integer.Parse(parts(0))
Dim seconds As Integer = Integer.Parse(parts(1))
```

Comment: Thanks this is useful too. I will try to implement both ways so I have an example of it. Cheers.